# progressBar блокируется потоком android

Tags: android

```
 progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
    ConnectedClass connectedClass = ConnectedClass.createInstance(devToConnect.getPairBluDev(), mHandler);
    ConnectedClass.createInstance(devToConnect.getPairBluDev(), mHandler);
    connectedClass.start();

    connectedClass.join();
```

Мне нужно чтоб прогресс бар просто крутился пока выполняется задача в  connectedClass, я его сделал отдельным поток специально чтоб освободить основной поток. Но  progressBar всё равно появляется только после выполнение операции в потоке.
connectedClass.join()- я ставлю так как мне нужно ждать результата чтоб проверить его уже в главном потоке. Какими способами я могу заставить его просто крутиться пока не закончится выполнение другого потока?
Я проверял два потока работают.

Comment: "When we invoke the join() method on a thread, the calling thread goes into a waiting state. It remains in a waiting state until the referenced thread terminates." https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-join

Comment: Иными словами очень похоже что вы блокируете основной поток этим самым `join()`, поэтому он и отрисовывает только тогда, когда освободится.

Comment: но если я уберу join  то проверка выполнится раньше чем отработает поток. вот не понимаю как мне выйти из этой ситуации

Comment: Второй поток как закончит работу должен вызвать в основном потоке код, который уберет прогрессбар. Посмотрите AsyncTask в SDK, он сам по себе морально устарел, но его паттерн как раз об этом.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы не блокировать основной поток, рекомендуется использовать асинхронные потоки.

Суть асинхронных потоков в использовании callback'ов, которые по завершению будут вызываться в конце работы. Для того, чтобы это сделать, создайте простой интерфейс:

```java
interface ConnectivityResultListener{
   void onDone();
}
```

Вы можете дополнить этот интерфейс аргументами, если это необходимо, например, для получения результата работы API.

Далее, нужно прописать конец задачи. Сделать это можно так, например:

```
public void start(ConnectivityResultListener listener){
   //Ваш код
   listener.onDone();
}
```

И просто использовать это. Например, вот так:

```java
progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
ConnectedClass connectedClass = 
ConnectedClass.createInstance(devToConnect.getPairBluDev(), mHandler);
connectedClass.start(() -> {
   progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
});
```

Comment: Создал интерфейс передаю реализацию его метода в конструктор  ConnectedClass connectedClass = ConnectedClass.createInstance(devToConnect.getPairBluDev(), mHandler, new ConnectivityResultListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDone() {
                        Log.d(TAG, "ПОДКЛЮЧИЛСЯ и Вызвал этот метод ");
                    }
                });
                connectedClass.start(); И получаю ошибку Animators may only be run on Looper threads когда вызывается метод интерфейса из другого потока. я новичек и может что не так делаю?

Comment: Убрал работу с textviev и всё остальное из этого метода. и прогресбар стал отключаться. Но как мне теперь вызвать проверку из основного потока?:  if (mySocket.isConnected) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                button.setEnabled(false);
                buttonSend.setEnabled(true); .... и т.д. если подключился я выполняю ряд действий. Наверное уже наворотил слишком много но как то нужно дорулить это. Спасибо за подсказки

Comment: Я почему то забыл про хандлер. Всё оказалось просто. подключение запускаю в другом потоке и в конце потока посылаю сообщение хандлером в main. Вопрос Закрыть. Всем спасибо